# Modify existing script to only hold data for two weeks

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have the following script:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat ontape.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#

ssh root@server1 mkdir -p /home/mybackup/ontape/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
ssh root@server2 mkdir -p /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

for server in $(cat /root/servers.txt)

do
   scp /dbbackup/backupdb/ontape/fullsize/* "$server/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

done
     echo 'Files have been moved' | mail -s "ONTAPE FILES MOVED" email@dommain.com
   rm -f /dbbackup/backupdb/ontape/fullsize/*
```

Which this is working correctly. However my disk is getting full so I need it to only hold data for two weeks and get rid of anything else. Can someone give me an example and show me how I would add this in my current script?

Comment: *which* disk is getting full? You don't keep data on your local machine.

Comment: The disk on one of the servers is getting full because of the backup jobs. I only need to hold the data for two weeks. /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup 947GB

Comment: You'll have to clarify which files you want this script to remove; there's /home/mybackup, /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup, and /dbbackup

Comment: Right now it currently has no purging in the script or removing after the a while so what ever gets copied to it gets copied but its taking to much space that is why I need the script to have something in it that says delete data older then two weeks or something like that.

Comment: I need the script to remove these files  /home/mybackup, /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup which is on the remote server..

Comment: so on server1 & server2  which our the remote server that is where I create the folder with the year-month-date and in there is the file called backup.lo which is 37GB or so. I only need to keep two weeks of data. Does that make since?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `cron` job on each server in order to find and delete old backups every morning:

```
30 02 * * * /usr/bin/find /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup -type f -mtime +14 -print -delete
```

This `cron` entry will execute the `find` command every morning at 02:30.  The `find` command finds every file in the directory that is older than 14 days old, prints the file name (which will be logged), and deletes the file.

Comment: Ok that is a good idea. I could just setup a cronjob to run and do the above command... what exactly does this cron do? looks like it keeps data for 14 days two weeks is that correct?

Comment: Here is what I did. I added the following cronjob in my /etc/crontab and I then ran it for 31 07 it did not do anything. Question in the /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup/ there are directories in which get created via the script that look like this 2017-09-13, etc.... will that matter? Or do I need to run the cronjob as root? I am logged in as root.

Comment: ok got it to work. had to add root in the front. Thanks for your help with this.